# Adicionar uma nova variavel a um componente(PictureBox)

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Estou criando um jogo para um trabalho na faculdade, esse jogo consiste em varias `Picturebox`, uma é o personagem principal que anda, pula e atira, a `PictureBox` dos tiros e a `PictureBox` dos monstros(gerada aleatoriamente por um `Random`), atualmente, quando o programa detecta a colisão da picturebox dos tiros com a do monstro, o monstro é deletado e o tiro também.

O que eu gostaria de fazer é deixar esses monstros tendo uma "vida", por exemplo, demorar 3 tiros para o monstro morrer, mas para isso tenho que criar uma variavel "int vida" e correlacionar ela com a `PictureBox` do monstro que foi criado e não sei como fazer isso

Esta é a parte do código onde os monstro são criados:

```
Random random = new Random();
int a = random.Next(0, 300);
if (a == 150)
{
  NovoMonstro();
}
```

Este é o Metódo NovoMonstro:

```
PictureBox monstro = new PictureBox();
Bitmap imagem;
imagem = Properties.Resources.monstro;
monstro.Image = imagem;
monstro.Size = new Size(51, 85);
monstro.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
monstro.Tag = "monstros";
monstro.Left = 1024;
monstro.Top = 555;
monstro.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
this.Controls.Add(monstro);
monstro.BringToFront();
```

Esta é a parte do programa da colisão entre o tiro e o monstro:

```
foreach (Control y in this.Controls)
{
    foreach (Control j in this.Controls)
    {
        if (y is PictureBox && (y.Tag == "bulletD" || y.Tag == "bulletE"))
        {
            if (j is PictureBox && (j.Tag == "monstros" || j.Tag == "monstrosinvertidos"))
            {  
                //detecta se teve colisão entre as picturebox
                if (y.Bounds.IntersectsWith(j.Bounds))
                {
                    this.Controls.Remove(j);
                    this.Controls.Remove(y);
                    contador++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A geração de monstros esta dentro de um `Timer` e a colisão tambem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução será criar uma classe que extenda o tipo `PictureBox` e adicionar uma propriedade `Vida`:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class MyPictureBox : PictureBox
    {
        public int Vida { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Compile o projeto e utilize o componente `MyPictureBox` ao invés da `PictureBox` nativa.

A partir deste momento terá a propriedade acessível no código para poder manipular.

Comment: Sim, eu consegui resolver o problema ontem fazendo exatamente isso, eu não sabia que era possivel criar uma picturebox ou um componente qualquer "personalizado" e adicionar o tipo de variavel que eu desejar a ele, muito obrigado